# What colour ranges would a solution of Methyl Orange and Thymol Blue have

Tags: ph

Would the solution of Thymol blue and Methyl orange tell the difference between an acid with ph 2.1 and anther acid with ph 2.2?
I am a chemistry beginner, so I don't understand the reactions on that good of a level.

Comment: It is rather a question, if your eye is able to tell the difference. [Thymol blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymol_blue) has range 1.2(red)-2.8(yellow), [methyl orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_orange) 3.1(red)-4.4(yellow). So effectively 1.2(red)-2.8(orange=yellow+red). It is possible, but I would not bet on being able to notice 0.1 pH difference, putting it side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of this question depends on the relative amount of Thymol blue and Methyl orange. If the acidic mixture contains roughly equal amounts of the indicators, or more Methyl orange, the only thing to be observed in an acidic solution is that its color is red up to about pH $4$, where Methyl orange turns yellowish. If the Methyl orange is present in rather small amounts, its effect of the color change would not be significant : the color change from red to yellow would be visible at about pH $2$. Whatever your choice of indicators, there will not be any visible difference between pH $2.1$ and pH $2.2$.